# Custom action_item with custom method in Active Admin

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-5, activeadmin

I have a nested resource in Active Admin which shows all SupportSessions (like meetings) for a particular SupportAllocation (which defines a teacher-pupil relationship):

```
ActiveAdmin.register SupportSession do
  belongs_to :support_allocation
```

On my index page, I'd like a button at the top that the user can click (like they can click 'New Support Session'), which then executes a custom method which sends an email using ApplicationMailer. There is no 'page' where the button goes to - it just redirects back to the current index page with a message indicating success or otherwise.

I can get the 'Request Approvals' button to appear on the index page with this code:

```
  # Adds a new button
  action_item only: :index  do
      link_to 'Request approvals', send_for_approval #custom method
  end
```

But obviously this raises an exception:

```
undefined local variable or method `send_for_approval'
```

Because I haven't defined this custom method anywhere.

I've created my mailer class but I'm not sure how to 'connect' it to my resource. I realise this will involve a new route of some sort, or use the existing 'put' method. I'd need to hand the current SupportAllocation ID to the method, so it knows which records/data to deal with when it sends email messages.

Any tips on how do I do create a button that runs this custom method + parameter? Where do I define this new custom method?

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Did my answer help you?

Comment: Yes thank you - it's great. But it doesn't quite work yet. I've posted a comment below. I think I've complicated it with my nested resources. (Also not sure if this is best as a member or collection action.)

Comment: As you said you need the record id, you have no other choice than making it a member action

Comment: That's correct. But the ID is for the resource nested above it - so the user has already selected a support_allocation ID. Now they're looking at all support_sessions (of which there are many on this page, no specific ID) for the current support allocation (specific ID). My custom method would send an email which includes ALL support sessions for the current support allocation: i.e. it sends an email which isn't restricted to any particular support session ID.

Answer (score 3):

You should code the action first, in your file:

```
member_action :send_for_approval, method: :patch do
  # send your email here you can access to :resource which is your record
  YourMailer.with(support_session_id: resource.id).your_email.deliver_now
  # redirect to your admin index or show path
end
```

Then `rails routes` will give you the correct path to it so you can pass it to `action_item`, it will look something like that:

```
action_item only: :index  do
   link_to 'Request approvals', send_for_approval_admin_support_session_path, method: :patch
end
```

References:

https://activeadmin.info/8-custom-actions.html#member-actions

https://activeadmin.info/8-custom-actions.html#action-items

Comment: This is fantastic! Thank you. It almost works... The error I get is something to do with the path, I think ('undefined local variable or method' in the link_to part of action_item). If I rake routes I can see a new route is generated, but this is a nested resource remember: request_approval_support_allocation_support_session. However, if I use request_approval_support_allocation_support_session_path in link_to it still creates an exception.

Comment: Sorry, that should read: 'request_approval_support_allocation_support_sessions_path' - but this still raises and exception error (my method is called request_approval).

Comment: @ChrisKenworthy Oh yes I forgot that, if you made a `:patch` action as suggested in my answer the link should be: `link_to 'Request approvals', request_approval_support_allocation_support_sessions_path, method: :patch` I'll update the answer